# Cognito Forgot password for Admin authentication in .net core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am performing admin authentication of the user and need to perform the Forgot password with Cognito. in Web API
However I am not providing an option for Multifactor authentication (where in cognito sends the confirmation code either to email or password, I am using my own notification service to do that) , So I just need the cognito to accept the reset the password as an admin. and set the new password to username. Is there any way it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Cognito does not support setting newPassword for user by admin.